# Confused on PIC 18F4620

Tags: pic, led

I can't realize, why my code doesn't work properly? Here is this simple code:

```
 void main() {

     TRISB = 0;
     TRISD = 0;

     while(1)
     {
          LATD.RB6 = 1;
          Delay_ms(1000);
          LATD.RB6 = 0;
          Delay_ms(1000);
          LATD.RD0 = 1;
          Delay_ms(1000);
          LATD.RD0 = 0;
          Delay_ms(1000);
     }
}
```

The effect of the code is that the LED on RD0 is flashing, and the LED on RD1 is permanently turned on! On RB6 there is nothing happening.

Note, that I'm using a development board, with Tiny Bootloader.

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo - Latch D does not have pin B6! Change `LATD.RB6` to `LATB.RB6` and it should work.

If you do not want RD1 to be on, you can just do `LATD.RD1 = 0`

Fixed code:

```
void main() {

 TRISB = 0;
 TRISD = 0;

 LATD.RD1 = 0;
 while(1){
      LATB.RB6 = 1;
      Delay_ms(1000);
      LATB.RB6 = 0;
      Delay_ms(1000);
      LATD.RD0 = 1;
      Delay_ms(1000);
      LATD.RD0 = 0;
      Delay_ms(1000);
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I shouldn't copy-paste sections when writing code. Thank you! :)